# Insert text in <img> source between text and file type using jQuery or Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some image elements that I want to add additional text to when the user clicks a button.

```
<img class="torso" src="img/girl/body/girl001.png" alt="">
<img class="eyebrows" src="img/eyebrows/black.png" alt="">
<img class="face face1" src="img/face/head1_1.png" alt="">

<button>Tilt Images</button>
```

The text would need to be added before the ".png" and would end up looking like this:

```
<img class="torso" src="img/girl/body/girl001-tilt.png" alt="">
<img class="eyebrows" src="img/eyebrows/black-tilt.png" alt="">
<img class="face face1" src="img/face/head1_1-tilt.png" alt="">

<button>Untilt Images</button>
```

With "-tilt" being added to the image source name before the .png file type effectively swapping out the image with the "-tilt" version. All the image names are different in length however, I figured if I somehow used .find(); on the attr(); for the ".png" and used prepend(); to add the "-tilt" string it would work... I've just been racking my brain on how to achieve this. Any help/knowledge is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple toggle button to toggle between the image's -tilt and untitlt version. To change the src, you can simply reassign it using [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', e => {
  let t = e.target.innerText;
  e.target.innerText = t === 'untilt images' ? 'tilt images' : 'untilt images'
  document.querySelectorAll('#images > img').forEach(img => {
    img.src = img.src.replace(/(\-tilt)?\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/, (_, tilt, type) =>
      tilt ? '.' + type : '-tilt.' + type
    );
    console.log(img.src);
  });
})
```

```html
<div id="images">
  <img class="torso" src="img/girl/body/girl001.png" alt="">
  <img class="eyebrows" src="img/eyebrows/black.png" alt="">
  <img class="face face1" src="img/face/head1_1.png" alt="">
</div>

<button id="toggle">tilt Images</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done in a more or less modular way with `data-` attributes and native JS. Bind the logic on the button click event, do some string replace on the image source, change the button text and that's it.

**EDIT**

It was not asked for in the question, but this script also handles all kinds of file endings and ensures that `-tilted` can be only once at the end of the file name.

```js
const getTilted = (src) => src.replace(/(.*)\.(.*)/, "$1-tilted.$2");
const getUntilted = (src) => src.replace(/(.*)-tilted\.(.*)/, "$1.$2");

document.querySelector('#tilt').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let images = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(this.dataset.tiltSelector));
  if(this.dataset.status === 'not-tilted') {
    for(let image of images) {
      image.src = getTilted(image.src);
      image.alt = getTilted(image.alt);
    }
    this.innerHTML = this.dataset.tiltedText;
    this.dataset.status = 'tilted';
  } else {
    for(let image of images) {
      image.src = getUntilted(image.src);
      image.alt = getUntilted(image.alt);
    }
    this.innerHTML = this.dataset.notTiltedText;
    this.dataset.status = 'not-tilted';
  }
});
```

```html
<img class="tiltable torso" src="img/girl/body/girl.001.ab.png" alt="img/girl/body/girl.001.ab.png"><br>
<img class="tiltable eyebrows" src="img/eyebrows/pre.black.jpeg" alt="img/eyebrows/pre.black.jpeg"><br>
<img class="tiltable face face1" src="img/tilted-faces/head1_1.a_c.svg" alt="img/tilted-faces/head1_1.a_c.svg"><br>

<button id="tilt" data-not-tilted-text="Tilt images" data-tilted-text="Untilt images" data-status="not-tilted" data-tilt-selector=".tiltable">Tilt images</button>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, added `.alt` to showcase it in the preview

Comment: Pretty extreme array function overuse now

Comment: True, the part with rewriting filenames could also be done easily with regex, but lately i did so much with map/reduce etc, stuck in that loop of thought :)

Comment: Get out of it. It's slower and you don't need to repeat code multiple times just to replace a string. :)

Comment: I was probably too excited to make this with map or reduce - and yes it was overkill, made now a simple string replace with regex.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple **[`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** operation:

**Vanilla JavaScript:**

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", tilt);

// Get all the images into an Array
let imgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("img"));

function tilt(){
  // Loop over the array items
  imgs.forEach(function(img){
    // Replace the old src with an updated value
    img.src = img.src.indexOf("-tilt.png") > -1 ? img.src.replace("-tilt", "") : img.src.replace(".png", "-tilt.png") ;
  });
  console.log(imgs);
}
```

```html
<img class="torso" src="img/girl/body/girl001.png" alt="">
<img class="eyebrows" src="img/eyebrows/black.png" alt="">
<img class="face face1" src="img/face/head1_1.png" alt="">
<button>Tilt/Untilt Images</button>
```

**JQuery:**

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
  // Loop over the JQuery wrapped set
  $("img").each(function(idx,img){
    // Replace the old src with the new one
    img.src = img.src.indexOf("-tilt.png") > -1 ? img.src.replace("-tilt", "") : img.src.replace(".png", "-tilt.png") ;
  });

  console.log($("img"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="torso" src="img/girl/body/girl001.png" alt="">
<img class="eyebrows" src="img/eyebrows/black.png" alt="">
<img class="face face1" src="img/face/head1_1.png" alt="">
<button>Tilt/Untilt</button>
```

Comment: Compact but no buttons to tilt/un-tilt so only partial solution

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Don't know how I missed that part. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks, this was a lot of help!

Comment: @JoelMcCann You're welcome. The way you can let people know that their answers were helpful is to up vote them and to mark the one that helped the most as "the" answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.